# How to fetch data from _vti_bin/listdata.svc using node js

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, listdata.svc, nodejs

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get data from the _vti_bin/listdata.svc on my sharepoint online site.

Essentially I am trying to fetch the data in this listdata.svc file to then insert it into an s3 bucket.
I've tried making a get request to the url but get a 403 Forbidden error, I'm assuming this is because I did not provide any credentials with this request. How can I provide my credentials so SharePoint can allow the request?

Here's a sample of the code that makes the call:

```
axios.get('https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/etc')
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node-sp-auth`. I've used it before and it's really simple to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sp-auth